Cohort saliency analysis in Python
I trained a CNN model to predict clinically relevant parameters by using images as inputs. Now I want to do a cohort GradCAM analysis on the images that were used in the test set to see where the model was focusing. I have already generated the heatmaps for each patient but now I am not sure how to proceed. One thought is, to sum up all the heatmaps and take the mean out of this summation. Any suggestions would be helpful.
